# How get complex fluid layout without nested weights

Tags: android, android-layout

How to get a layout like

[image: Desired Layout]

Where the height of the bottom elements is wrap_content, but with nested layout Eclipse hint me with `nested weights are bad for performance`

Comment: If you have only three elements with nested weights don't worry about performance and just ignore the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's vertical linear layout with weight 1 and a nested horizontal linear layout, wrap content high and weight 1 wide.  Yes, nested weights are bad for performance but if that's what you need, that's what you need.  In your case, as Mr. Moecklin points out, it is probably not significant.

**Edited to add:**

You probably already have this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The layout does not need a single root element?

Comment: @rkmax: thanks for pointing that out.  It was all there, but not all marked 'pre' so it was being ignored.  Much appreciated.

Comment: So in the end, the only solution is nested weights

Comment: Not the only but, in this case, the best.  The lint warning is quite correct: because of the layout algorithm, nested weights can be incredibly expensive.  In this case, though, because the nestings are orthogonal and shallow, you really should be fine.  Use hierarchyviewer to check, if you are still worried.